# Which version should i download for libxml2 for linux?

Tags: c, xml, linux, qt-creator, libxml2

I want to use libxml2 library but confused with which version should i download for programming in linux,I would be programming in QTCreator so after download,I would link external library and choose the Libxml2.so file path and folder with include file apart from this. Do i also need to install it ? If yes, please tell installation steps..I am a beginner with linux ..Please provide appropriate link for libxml2 download

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use your distribution's package manager and install the package.  For Fedora this would be libxml2-devel, for Debian libxml2-dev…

Comment: I am using redhat can you please provide link

Comment: Google "red hat installing packages". First result: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Installing.html